# passing multiple arguments to python script throwing 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple python function to parse an excel sheet and generate SQL statements out of it.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys

def sqlscriptgen(filename,sheetname,column1,column2,column3):
    import xlrd
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        a = sheet.cell_value(i,column1)
        b = sheet.cell_value(i,column2)
        c = sheet.cell_value(i,column3)
        if c.lower() == "delete":
            print ("DROP USER '" + a +"'@'" + b +"';")
        else:
            pass

sqlscriptgen((sys.argv[1]) (sys.argv[2]) (sys.argv[3]) (sys.argv[4]) (sys.argv[5]))
```

While the function works as expected. I saved it as sqlscriptgenerator.py and when i try to execute as:

```
python3 sqlscriptgenerator.py "/mnt/d/MySQL/DB Priv_Details.xls" "sheet1" "1" "2" "3"
```

I am getting below error :

```
File "sqlscriptgenerator.py", line 18, in <module>
    sqlscriptgen((sys.argv[1]) (sys.argv[2]) (sys.argv[3]) (sys.argv[4]) (sys.argv[5]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am sure there is something that i am not doing appropriately while passing arguments, but could not find out whats wrong and how to correct it.

Thanks
Udhayan

Comment: You need to separate the arguments with commas (`,`), and the wrapping parenthesis are not necessary: `sqlscriptgen(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5])`. What happens now is that Python is trying to do something like `"sheet1"("1")` which is a function call and as the error states strings are not callable

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo . I tried that but i am getting a different error now                                          
   **  File "sqlscriptgenerator.py", line 18, in <module>
    sqlscriptgen(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5])
  File "sqlscriptgenerator.py", line 10, in sqlscriptgen
    a = sheet.cell_value(i,column1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 419, in cell_value
    return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str **

Comment: Because `argv` elements are always strings. If you want, you need to convert them to ints...

Comment: cool. Thanks @Tomerikoo.. i got it now .. fixed it.